# Dynamic SQL Top() clause in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio, ip-warming

I am looking to automate an IP Warm Up process. We have our plan that defines the number of contacts that should be sent to on each day across each domain group.

I would like to automate this, so am looking at how I can create a dynamic Top() clause that will select the correct number of contacts to push into a Send DE each day based on the plan.

**DE: Warm_Up_Plan**

Fields: Domain_Group | Volume | Send_Date
Example: Gmail | 400 | 9/11/2023 12:00:00 AM

**DE: Gmail_Group_Contacts DE**

Fields: Id | Email | Domain_Group
Example: 001 | example@gmail.com | Gmail

**Send_Out DE**

Fields: Id

The automation should look at the record in Warm_Up_Plan with today's date and the correct domain, and then select that many people from the Gmail_Group_Contacts. I have tried doing something like the below SQL query, however it errors with the message:

```sql
SELECT TOP (w.volume) g.id FROM Gmail_Group_Contacts g
INNER JOIN Warm_Up_Plan w
on w.Domain_Group = g.Domain_Group
WHERE w.Send_Date = '9/11/2023 12:00:00 AM'
AND w.Domain_Group = 'Verizon'
```

> Error Message: The reference to column "volume" is not allowed in an argument to a TOP, OFFSET, or FETCH clause. Only references to columns at an outer scope or standalone expressions and subqueries are allowed here.

How can I make the Top() clause dynamic so that it pulls through the value in this manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice solution by Adam.

a different alternative I sometimes use is to store the "TOP" number in a control table with key/value pairs, and look it up based on some condition (e.g. id could be each day, considering timezones etc).

controlSettings (pseudo dates)

```
id,controlparameterKey,controlParameterValue
today,batchsize,5000
tomorrow,batchsize,10000
day after tomorrow,batchsize,15000
```

(pseudo date condition)

```
SELECT TOP 
  (SELECT 
    CAST(controlParameterValue AS INT) AS intValue



  FROM controlSettings 
  WHERE controlParameterKey = 'batchsize'
  AND id = today
  )


whateverField
FROM 
YourDE
```

if your controlParameterValue field is a number, you can omit the CAST AS, and just SELECT controlParameterValue.

I included the CAST as I usually use the control table for more than just one kind of parameter, and "controlParameterValue" might be a text field. My usecase is not IP warming, just wanted to chip that in as well as I frequently come back to this solution myself and I have to look it up somewhere ;)

Comment: Thank you @Jonas Lamberty, I followed this approach and it is working as hoped!

Answer (score 3):

You could do use the `row_number()` window function to assign a sequential number to each row (in random order) and then only select rows that less than or equal to your volume value. Something like this:

```sql
SELECT 
  x.id
, x.rowNum
from (

  select
    g.id 
  , w.volume
  , row_number() over (order by newid()) as rowNum
  FROM Gmail_Group_Contacts as g
  INNER JOIN Warm_Up_Plan as w on w.Domain_Group = g.Domain_Group
  WHERE w.Send_Date = '9/11/2023 12:00:00 AM'
  AND w.Domain_Group = 'Verizon'

) x
where 1=1
and x.rowNum <= x.volume
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but might help future readers.

You can use the structure `SELECT TOP (w.volume) g.id FROM Gmail_Group_Contacts g`, if you wrap it in a `CROSS APPLY` statement.

```sql
SELECT g.* FROM Warm_Up_Plan w
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP (w.volume) g.id
    FROM Gmail_Group_Contacts g
    WHERE w.Domain_Group=g.Domain_Group
) g
WHERE w.Send_Date = '9/11/2023 12:00:00 AM'
AND w.Domain_Group = 'Verizon'
```